# How to retrieve the source code of an XQuery module stored in eXist-db?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am looking for a way how to retrieve the source code of an XQuery module stored in the database.

Is there any way how to do this using eXist-db's REST API or an XQuery extension function or any other eXist-db interface?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "metadata" and "xquery definition" here? Do you mean you want to see the source code of an XQuery file? Or you want to know about the signatures of functions defined in an XQuery module? Or do you want its created and last modified dates, ownership properties, etc.?

Comment: Hello, sorry for not being clear. Yes I mean the source code of an XQuery file.

Comment: Great, I've edited the question to reflect your answers, so others looking for the answer to the same question can find it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the REST Server, you have two main options:

1. Do a GET on the XQuery stored in the db, with the query string parameter `_source=yes`. You need to change some settings in `$EXIST_HOME/descriptor.xml` to enable that.
2. Write a query for retrieving queries. A query stored in the database is like any other binary document, so you could use `util:binary-doc()` to get it.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, option one (adding the "_source=yes" to url query string) worked for me.